# Veracode Greenlight scan in multimodule maven projects

Tags: java, maven, veracode

I'm trying to scan a maven project using greenlight. It runs smoothly when the project is single module (src and target folder are at the root) but fails when is multi-module. Multimódule means :

```
root
  -- module-one
       -- src
       -- target
  -- module-two
       -- src
       -- target
```

and so on.

The greenlight jar is looking for builds in the wrong place and I can not found any way to indicate the correct path

**java -jar gl-scanner-java.jar [params...] -b target/classes**
The results is the expectec because the target classes folder is not there

```
GREENLIGHT SEVERE: Provided build directory 'path/./target/classes' is not a directory or not accessible: skipping pair #1.
```

**java -jar gl-scanner-java.jar [params...] -b module-one/target/classes**
The build path is wrong:

```
Source file:   module-one/src/main/java/.../ByteCodeChange.java
Build file:   module-one/module-one/target/classes/.../ByteCodeChange.class
```

And of course fail:

```
GREENLIGHT SEVERE: Unable to create JAR 'path/module-one/module-one/target/classes/.../ByteCodeChange.class': Problem accessing input file: module-one/module-one/target/classes/.../ByteCodeChange.class (No such file or directory)
```

Does not matter about the -b paramater is passed, it will never found the correct build path but take a look the source file found is the correct one.

Could some one help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try specifying multiple source and build directories:

```
-s module-one/src/main/java,module-two/src/main/java \
-b module-one/target/classes,modules-two/target/classes
```

Comment: Great!. Thanks a lot Michael. Works fine